# How to select the first value that is not NaN after using groupby().agg()?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have the following code:

```
df.groupby(["id", "year"], as_index=False).agg({"brand":"first", "color":"first"})
```

However, I have some values that are NaN. I want to select the first value that is not NaN.

Suppose my dataframe looks like this:

| id | year | brand | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2010 | NaN | Blue |
| 001 | 2010 | Audi | NaN |
| 001 | 2010 | **Audo** | Blue |
| 001 | 2011 | Bmw | NaN |
| 001 | 2011 | NaN | NaN |
| 001 | 2012 | BMW | Green |
| 002 | 2010 | Tesla | White |

I want to find all unique combinations of id and year,i.e. `df.groupby(["id", "year"])` and then find the first non-NaN value. The motivation behind this is that a have a large and messy data set with many missing values and many typos. In the example table I also simulated a typo. Note that it is irrelevant whether the typo is first and gets chosen, as long as I keep track of the data per combination of id and year. Typos are a completely separate problem for now.

The desired output would be:

| id | year | brand | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2010 | Audi | Blue |
| 001 | 2011 | BMW | NaN |
| 001 | 2012 | BMW | Green |
| 002 | 2010 | Tesla | White |

Comment: You mean you want to make that a new column. containing the first value that is not NaN? It would be helpful to provide a sample dataframe

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. I added a table as an example

Comment: Your question still looks confusing. Based on the provided dataframe, how does your desired output look like? Can you include that to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will produce the below output.

```py
df1 = df.groupby(['id', 'year']).agg({
    'brand': lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0] if x.dropna().any() else np.nan,
    'color': lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0] if x.dropna().any() else np.nan,
}).reset_index()
print(df1)
```

Using a costume function:

```
def get_first_non_nan(x):
    return x.dropna().iloc[0] if x.dropna().any() else np.nan
    
df1 = df.groupby(['id', 'year']).agg({
    'brand': get_first_non_nan,
    'color': get_first_non_nan,
}).reset_index()
print(df1)
```

---

```
    id  year  brand  color
0  001  2010   Audi   Blue
1  001  2011    Bmw    NaN
2  001  2012    BMW  Green
3  002  2010  Tesla  White
```

Comment: I have little experience with lambda functions. Can I also define the lambda function as a python function and then call the same function twice, once for brand and once for color?

Comment: Yes you can do that. what you will have to do is to create a costume function. I can help you with that. Give me a moment please. I will edit the answer to include a costume function at the bottom.